# Do search engines respect the HTTP header field “Content-Location”?

Tags: http, http-headers, search-engine

I was wondering whether search engines respect the [HTTP header field `Content-Location`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.14).

This could be useful, for example, when you want to remove the session ID argument out of the URL:

```
GET /foo/bar?sid=0123456789 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
…

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Location: http://example.com/foo/bar
…
```

---

**Clarification:**
I don’t want to redirect the request, as removing the session ID would lead to a completely different request and thus probably also a different response. I just want to state that the enclosed response is also available under its “main URL”.

Maybe my example was not a good representation of the intent of my question. So please take a look at [What is the purpose of the HTTP header field “Content-Location”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447679/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-http-header-field-content-location).

Comment: Isn't this stretching the purpose of Content-Location a little bit? The spec makes it sound like there should be a bigger difference than just the query string.

Comment: Removing the query was just an example. But may be I’ve misunderstood the purpose of Content-Location and it is not to provide the real location of the requested resource.

Comment: I think that's exact purpose, but I think the idea would be more like
URI: http://foo.com/listOfStuff/indexOfResult (basically, identifying a specific member of a collection)
Content-Location: http://foo.com/path/to/individualItem (basically, direct URI to resource)

I think your idea is fine, tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Google just announced the answer to my question: [the `canonical` link relation for declaring the canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

[Maile Ohye](http://www.google.com/s2/profiles/112810134285899618775) from Google wrote:

> > MickeyC said...
> >     You should have used the Content-Location header instead, as per:
> >     http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
> >     "14.14 Content-Location"
>
> @MikeyC: Yes, from a theoretical standpoint that makes sense and we certainly considered it. A few points, however, led us to choose :
>
> 1. Our data showed that the "Content-Location" header is configured improperly on many web sites. Sometimes webmasters provide long, ugly URLs that aren’t even duplicates -- it's probably unintentional. They're likely unaware that their webserver is even sending the Content-Location header.
>
>    It would've been extremely time consuming to contact site owners to clean up the Content-Location issues throughout the web. We realized that if we started with a clean slate, we could provide the functionality more quickly. With Microsoft and Yahoo! on-board to support this format, webmasters need to only learn one syntax.
> 2. Often webmasters have difficulty configuring their web server headers, but can more easily change their HTML. rel="canonical" seemed like a friendly attribute.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html?showComment=1234714860000#c8376597054104610625

Answer (score 1):

Most decent crawlers do follow Content-Location. So, yes, search engines respect the Content-Location header, although that is no guarantee that the URL having the sid parameter will not be on the results page.

Answer (score 0):

In 2009 Google started looking at URIs qualified as `rel=canonical` in the response body.

Looks like since 2011, links formatted as per RFC5988 are [also parsed from the header field `Link:`](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/06/supporting-relcanonical-http-headers.html). It is also clearly mentioned in the [Webmaster Tools FAQ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?rd=1#6) as a valid option.

Guess this is the most up-to-date way of providing search engines some extra hypermedia breadcrumbs to follow - thus allow keeping you to keep them out of the response body when you don't actually need to serve it as content.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to using 'Location' rather than 'Content-Location' use the proper HTTP status code in your response depending on your reason for redirect.  Search engines tend to favor permanent redirect (301) status vs temporary (302) status.

Comment: `Location:` redirect. `Content-Location:` no redirect, specifying canonical address.

Answer (score -4):

Try the "Location:" header instead.

Comment: That redirects, which the asker doesn't wish to happen.