# Can the canonical IRI depend on content negotiation?

Tags: rest, http, hyperlink, http-headers, semantic-web

Suppose my HTTP server code implements the GET method on `/example`, replying with either JSON or HTML [depending on the Accept header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4) and setting `Vary: Accept`. The same data are also available without content negotiation at `/example.json` and `/example.html`, respectively.

Would I be using the [canonical link relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) correctly if I set `Link: </example.json>;rel=canonical` on `/example` when serving JSON, but `Link: </example.html>;rel=canonical` when serving HTML?

(A similar scenario could be constructed for entirely user-facing pages when using `Accept-Language` to choose the default language, provided that I don’t want to pay the cost of a redirect.)

Comment: Related: the Content-Location header ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Location), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448328)), which for `/example` with `Accept: application/json` would point to `/example.json`.